# Missing NOOBS file at the download section of RPi website

Tags: pi-4, noobs

Hi Im new to Raspberry Pi and recently got Pi 4. When I was looking up videos to setting up the new RPi 4, I realised that the NOOBS file is nowhere to be found in the downloads section of the RPi website. What should I do to set up the RPi?

Answer (score 1):

> the NOOBS file is nowhere to be found in the downloads section of the RPi website

I was hoping that's because it is defunct, but such [appears not to be the case](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?keywords=noobs&sid=0f5736ef3002ca56eacfae4161da5def), so possibly they decided to stop recommending it.<sup>1</sup>  Experience around here implies it is *harder* to install and use than plain RpiOS, and creates more, not fewer, headaches for newbies.  And I'd bet that most of those people never use it for anything but RpiOS anyway. Meaning it is a pointless hassle.

> What should I do to set up the RPi?

Follow the instructions about [using the official imager](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/) and use it to install RpiOS (formerly Raspbian).

Since the imager presents options and downloads images, it could be that NOOBs will be one of them.  If so, don't use it anyway ;)

---

1. Perhaps worth noting that the 64-bit beta RpiOS is not there either, presumably because of the "beta" status.  So it does not mean anything not there is unavailable or discouraged.

Comment: RPF indeed have quietly moved to recommending single installs using pi imager. And just today there's an updated version of the imager that can also set some parameters (hostname, ssh, wifi credentials, locale) https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-imager-update-to-v1-6/

Comment: If you feel you need to run multiple operating systems on one card (and I can understand some folk do) then I would look at https://berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot